# What is the benefit of encapsulating a collection inside a class?

Tags: c#, abstraction, modeling

Please see the code below:

```
      public class Customer
    {
        private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get { return _orders; } } //This line

        internal void AddOrder(Order order)
        {
            _orders.Add(order);
        }
}
```

This is what I would expect to see.  I am looking at some code, however the line I have identified with a comment is replaced with this:

```
 public OrderCollection Orders { get; } = new OrderCollection();
```

What is the benefit of encapsulating the IEnumerable in a class like this? I am talking from the perspective of DDD - an area I am trying to sharpen up on.

Comment: Add behavior to the command. So, when you're trying to add the order, you could validate the order for consistency against business rules before allowing them to corrupt the state of your object. Also, you can create specific business "SELECTs" to your collection, such as "MaxValue", "BiggestDiscount", "TotalDiscount", "TotalNumberOfItems", etc. etc. etc.

Comment: How is `OrderCollection` defined? Does it have some specific methods not available in other generic collection types? If the answer to this is "yes", then you know the benefit.

Comment: Probably the original author of this "improvement" had it too easy so far with serializing useless container classes, but is very excited about class templates provided by his or her favorite editor.

Comment: Read up on the .net framework design guidelines. Collection classes, generic or not, can enable reuse of code as well as enforce system invariants. Guidelines recommend encapsulation if you need either of these features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your original code example, is that `Orders` breaks the encapsulation of `_orders` as you are returning the list. Cast that `IEnumerable<Order>` to `IList<Order>` and code outside the class can start modifying the contents.

My guess therefore is that `OrderCollection` is used to prevent this occurring. It isn't necessary to do that though: `yield return` offers a far simpler way of maintaining the encapsulation:

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders 
    {
        get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
    }

    internal void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach.

Comment: Is it possible to do this if I am using NHibernate as the ORM? Can _orders be private? +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, and it is private in the example

Comment: @w0051977, I don't think this works with NHibernate because the `IEnumerable<Order>` is immutable.  NHibernate needs to be able to add and remove values when it syncs up to the dataset.  I could be wrong though... Some of these tools can change the state of private members--which is scary.

Comment: @Berin Loritsch , it does seem to be possible as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/wiH1DPGOhgU.  I have asked another question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536695/cannot-use-nhibernate-code-mapping-for-a-private-field.  If it is not possible then surely this answer would be pointless (which I don't believe it is)?

Comment: Whether it does or not has no bearing on the usefulness of this answer.  If the intent is to provide a read-only API this answer identifies the correct way to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that whatever you persist is one model. The domain model is (could be) another one hidding the first.

Comment: I prefer something like `.Select(x=>x)` over hand coding an iterator.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, Yes, `Select` has it's place. It's simpler syntax, but has the overhead of calling the lambda for each item. It may well have been more appropriate here.

Comment: I have asked a follow on question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361876/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-object-when-using-nhibernate

Comment: Canonically better is  `list.AsReadOnly()`.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your question, you might be asking what is the benefit of using `OrderCollection` over `List<Order>`.  That is not what I originally answered (see below for the original answer).

I haven't seen class specific collections commonly used since Java and C# introduced generics to their languages.  Originally it was the only way to ensure the collection only worked with `Order` objects.  *If* that is the case, there is *no* benefit.

I have seen special cases where there are specific reasons to have a dedicated collection class:

- There is complicated logic to handle shifting the order of items in a list--example could be a list of things to process where the priority can change between iterations.
- There are summarization methods that are tied to the collection.
- Or some other application specific problem that you need to solve.

Current language features can make most reasons for a dedicated class for the collection a moot point.  For example extension functions in C# can work on any `IEnumrable<Order>` not just your special one.

The only place in recent history that I could justify a special encapsulation of a collection had to do with dynamic prioritization rules.  We had a round-robin processing queue for incoming data, but certain events would mark certain selectors as inactive or the cycle would have to stop short if it took more than X seconds.  The rules were very specific to the work queue management.  Every N seconds the processor would wake up and iterate over the list of active selectors to do work.  We didn't call it a collection, but that's essentially what it was.  We used the `yield return` and `yield break` to handle returning the next live selector or stop the processing cycle short.  The next iteration had to pick up at the place it left off.

Beyond that example, the maintenance overhead of having a dedicated collection implementation rarely is better than simply using a standard generic collection.

---

The only difference between the two code samples you showed was due to a C# feature introduced in .Net 4.6 called [read-only properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).  It extends the auto-property concept introduced in .Net 4.

This:

```
private OrderCollection _orders = new OrderCollection();

public OrderCollection Orders { get { return _orders; } }
```

Is functionally identical to this:

```
public OrderCollection Orders { get; } = new OrderCollection();
```

The only difference is that the compiler generates the backing variable and initializes it with the value on the right hand side.  When you access the `Orders` property, there is only a getter in both instances.

---

Now, the complete isolation of the `OrderCollection` implementation detail is addressed by David Amo's answer.  His solution is fundamentally different in that you are only ever exposing an `IEnumerable<Order>` and there is no way to get a reference to a mutable collection like the original code had.

Immutable enumeration is fundamentally different (courtesy of David Amo):

```
private OrderCollection _orders = new OrderCollection();

public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
{
    get { foreach (var order in _orders) yield return order; }
}
```

.Net 4.6 also introduced [lambda properties](http://developerpublish.com/lambda-and-getter-only-auto-properties-in-c-6-0/) which look like this:

```
public string FullName => string.Join(" ", FirstName, LastName);
```

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the .NET framework and C#. Expression bodied properties (lambda properties, as you refer to them) and initializers for auto properties were introduced with C# 6. These features will work with any version of the .NET framework.

Comment: I stand corrected.  The features were added with C# 6.  The confusion stemmed from C# 6 being released with .Net 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

`OrderCollection` looks like the sort of class that we had to create back in the early 21st century before generics.

What is the benefit of using this class? It's unknowable without seeing the class.

A class should guard its data against unwanted modification. Exposing a list allows other classes to add, remove, etc.

One option in this scenario is to expose the collection as a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class DontMessWithMyList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _myPrivateList;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> ListContents => _myPrivateList.AsReadOnly();
}
```

If your internal list is only exposed this way and its contents are immutable then other classes can't modify anything. They can only see it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the intention was not just to hide implementation of a single collection. Perhaps you have multiple collections of different types (array, list, dictionary) that need to be accessed? Then you should encapsulate and access through a single interface. Check out the iterator pattern.